# Windows Phone phonegap/cordova localstorage not saving data

Tags: cordova, local-storage, windows-phone

I have problem with localStorage in phonegap. There are two types of notation in localStorage:

1. localStorage.setItem["key", "value"]/localStorage.getItem["key"] (not working for me)

 2. localStorage.key (works fine, but not saving data, after relaunch application)

Comment: I had the same problem on WP8. It worked in Android and iOS, even on WP7 (although there is a plugin doing a job). It seems as WP8 counts each page as it is on different domain when accessed using `file://` protocol. Every page has its own localStorage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

are you using the square brackets? You´re setting up an array instead of calling a function.

try this:

```
localStorage.setItem("key", "value");

//get the value
localStorage.getItem("key");
```

Comment: Hi,Iam working on windows cordova..localStorage is not working when using it in different html pages in windows phone..Please help me..Thanks

Answer (score 0):

My **personal suggestion** would be don't use the local storage.Its not good for the long run,as it is almost deprecated and has a limitation in the storage size.

Use a plugin and adapt SQLITE database or anything that would not have restriction on the size of storage.

Comment: we always assume the asker WANTS to do/use what he´s asking about.

Comment: dan,it was just my suggestion.whatever i have experienced and read about it.

Comment: if someone wants to use localStorage, has the same problem and finds this questions on google, your answer would be just a waste of time because it doesn't solve the problem. However, this is what this site is for. Solving problems quickly.